# Unsigned integer print

Tags: c, printf

Why does this print -1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int i = -1;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

While this prints

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int i = -1;
    printf("%u", i);
    return 0;
}
```

the largest possible integer value

Also, why does this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c = printf("Hello");
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Print hello5 and not 5.

Counter-statement //for Eric

You mentioned about side-effect, right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i = 0;
for (; i++; printf("%d", i));
printf("%d", i);
return 0; 
}
```

Why does the printf ("%d",i) inside the for loop not print the value in this code as a side-effect?

Comment: C is not beginner friendly. You are doing things you should generally not do: storing an signed value in an unsigned variable. Also: the printf function writes to `stdout` by default, so why **wouldn't** you expect the "Hello" part to be printed? Take some time to play around with these things until you become familiar with them. You need to start to get a sense of what you're doing. For example to understand the difference between a value in-memory and a representation of that value somewhere else.

Comment: `printf("Hello\n")` does the trick

Comment: The 3rd question has nothing to do with the other 2. Please don't ask unrelated questions in the same question, better to split them up in several.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Question 1

> Why does this print -1…
>
> `unsigned int i=-1;`
> `printf ("%d",i);`

Formally, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, because `i` is an `unsigned int` but `%d` is for an `int`, and C 2018 7.21.6.1 9 says “If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.”

However, C has a history of conflating signed and unsigned types<sup>1</sup>, and many compilers tread lightly in this regard.<sup>2</sup> Typically, what happens is:

- The function call passes the `unsigned int` value of `i` by putting its bits in the place where an `unsigned int` argument should be passed.
- The `printf` gets the bits for an `int` from the place where an `int` argument should be passed.
- These are the same place.
- In consequence, `printf` reinterprets the bits that represent an `unsigned int` as if they were an `int`.

In `unsigned int i = -1`, −1 is converted to `unsigned int` according to rules in the C standard (6.3.1.3, see below) that result in the maximum `unsigned int` value, which has all bits set in its representation: 1111…1111<sub>2</sub>.

In reinterpreting those bits as `int`, most C implementations use two’s complement. In [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the bits 1111…1111<sub>2</sub> represent −1.

So `printf` takes the passed bits as the `int` value −1 and prints “-1”.

### Question 2

> While this prints…
>
> `unsigned int i=-1;`
> `printf ("%u",i);`
>
> … the largest possible integer value

The rule for converting −1 to `unsigned int` is in 6.3.1.3 2:

> … the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

“One more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type” is 1+`UINT_MAX`. Adding −1 to 1 + `UINT_MAX` produces `UINT_MAX`, which is representable in `unsigned int`, so that is the value stored in `i`. Printing this with `%u` prints its value normally.

### Question 3

> Also, why does this…
>
> `int c=printf ("Hello");`
> `printf ("%d",c);`
>
> … Print hello5 and not 5.

`printf` does two things:

- It writes characters to standard output. (The C standard calls this a *side effect* because it is something the function does besides returning a value.)
- It returns the number of characters written (or a negative value if an error occurred).

When you call `printf("Hello")`, it writes “Hello” to output and returns 5.

Then `printf("%d", c)` writes “5” to output.

The question suggests you think that using `printf` in an assignment or initialization causes only its return value to be used, suppressing the side effect. This is not so. Whenever an expression is evaluated in C, its side effect and main effect are evaluated.

(In fact, assignments are themselves expressions; `c = printf("Hello")` is an expression, and you can use it in further operations, such as `x = 3 * (c = 5)`, which will assign 15 to `x`. We can take any expression and put a semicolon after it to make an expression statement, which evaluates the expression and discards the main result. `printf("%d", c);` evaluates `printf` for its side effect and discards the return value.)

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> For example, 6.5.2.2 6 allows substituting a signed integer type for the corresponding unsigned integer type and vice-versa in calls to functions without prototypes, albeit limited to values representable in both. For prototypes with `...`, 7.16.1.1 allows the same substitution when using `va_arg`. The rules in 6.2.6.2 require value bits common to signed and unsigned types to have the same values.

<sup>2</sup> I do not recall any formal statement in regard to conflating signed and unsigned types, but I know compiler designers take some care to avoid breaking code with certain legacy use or certain not uncommon use cases even if the C standard does not require supporting them. In C, it is easy to slip and pass an `unsigned char` to be printed with `%u`, which is technically wrong because the `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: Please see edited question, I have another counter-example which I want to get clarified.

Comment: Kindly acknowledge if you saw my edited question.

Comment: @programmer: The body of that loop is never executed because the loop condition, `i++` is initially false since `i` starts as zero). Please do not add additional questions after the initial question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

On a system with 32-bit ints, both unsigned int -1 and signed int 2147483647 happen to have the same binary representation in memory (see [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

When passing the value to printf, the data type information is lost. Hence, printf relies on the format specifier (`%d` or `%u`) to determine whether the data was a signed or an unsigned integer.

---

About your second question: printf prints, regardless of whether you ignore the return value or not. Thus, the first line in your method prints `Hello`, the second one `5`.

Comment: How do you write binary representation of unsigned int i=-1?

Comment: Generally, we [advise against follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) on Stack Overflow. This can be asked as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. As pointed out by @lundin above, your original question is already compounded enough -- since it asks two things (though related).

Answer (score 2):

On the first question: It's the same representation in binary, but unsigned values won't use the last bit as a sign bit. @Heinzi's answer covers this more comprehensively.

Regarding

```
int c=printf ("Hello");
printf ("%d",c);
```

It prints `Hello5` because you've simply called printf twice:

1. Print `hello` and store the number of characters printed (5) in `c`.
2. Print the value of `c`, which is 5.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign -1 to an unsigned integer, it gets converted to a value representable in unsigned value using [*reduction modulo*](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9).

This

```
unsigned int i = -1;
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned int i = UINT_MAX;
```

And when you print `i` with `%d`, it's actually [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to format mismatch.

---

> Also, why does this [..] print hello5 and not 5.

The first printf call, `int c=printf ("Hello");`, still prints `Hello` and in the second you print the return value of previous printf's return value.
Hence `Hello5` output.

Comment: That's not undefined behavior since the binary representation is well defined.

Comment: @Cosinus For `%d`, the expected argument is `int` - otherwise, it's undefined. `UINT_MAX` can't be represented in an `int`, so it's certainly UB.

Comment: `printf` will however not lie down and die just because some line in chapter 7 of the standard says UB. But instead attempt to convert the passed data to the specified type. `int` and `unsigned int` alias and accessing one of them with the other won't cause any problems unless you are using a highly exotic/fictional system without 2's complement but with trap representations for negative zero etc.

Comment: And it's still remains undefined regardless of the number of qualifiers applied. Undefined means undefined - it doesn't mean "you'll certainly observe something bad. If not, it's OK".

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't know the type that you defined. It only knows how to interpret the value by the format specifier. So in your first example, you use `%d` which tells printf to read this value as a `signed int` and print it accordingly. In the second case you use `%u` sou it tells `printf` to interpret it as `unsigned int`.

The largest possible unsigned value has the same binary representation as `-1` for the same data type as `signed`, because the highest bit is interpreted as the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your your first dilemma, the answer is simple: `printf` uses the format specifier to decide on how to print the arguments passed to it, as stated by others as well.

For an `unsigned int`, the format is `%u`, while for a `signed int`, the format is `%d`.

See more information about the different format specifiers in the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html#DESCRIPTION):

> d, i
>
> The int argument is converted to signed decimal notation.
>
> o, u, x, X
>
> The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal
> (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and
> X) notation.

For your second dilemma:

> Also, why does this
>
> Print hello5 and not 5.

Because you told it to. There are two `printf` statements there. Assigning the result of `printf` does not "discard" the output of the `printf` itself -- it still prints out as instructed to. This (i.e. the I/O that functions like `printf` do) is called a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Your first `printf` indeed prints `"Hello"`, while your second prints out the return value of your first `printf` (the number of characters printed):

> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE
>
> Upon  successful  return,  these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

Answer (score -1):

For starters that's how integers work.

```
signed |             | unsigned
...    |  ...        | ...
 4     | 0000'0100b  | 4
 3     | 0000'0011b  | 3
 2     | 0000'0010b  | 2
 1     | 0000'0001b  | 1
 0     | 0000'0000b  | 0
-1     | 1111'1111b  | 255
-2     | 1111'1110b  | 254
-3     | 1111'1101b  | 253
-4     | 1111'1100b  | 252
...    | ...         | ...
```